# reading and updating file using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I created a log file using powershell in .txt or .config. Its look like :

```
# Hello
## This is readme.txt file
## This is commented line
# This is powershell command output
#
# File generated for read, re-load and edit the values
## -- many more comment is there
# Users can change values..
## There is no relation between $RegPath and $RegValue, this are only variables.

# this are registry path,
$RegPath = (
"\\hklm\software\microsoft\123",
"\\hklm\software\Adobe\123",
"\\hklm\software\Fax\123",
"\\hklm\software\IE\123");

# this are registry value.
$RegValue = (
"0",
"123",
"abc",
"456asdccxv",
"update",
"serv");

#this are some services with 0/1
# Win 7 OS exist
$IsWin7OS = 1

# Service pack installed
$IsSPInstalled = 0

# Check office
$MSOffice = 1

# This setting name is
$SettingName = "ReadMe.txt"
```

This is sample ReadMe.txt. I want to read this file in powershell and want to get values of $RegPath, $RegValue, $IsWin7OS, $IsSPInstalled, $MSOffice and $SettingName in powershell platform. Then I will update this value and save again in same file.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried so far, and where are you getting stuck with it?

Comment: I tried with 

    $filename = "C:\ReadFile.txt";
    $text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename)
    $text -replace "\(`r`n", '(' -replace "`r`n\)", ')' -split     "`r`n" | % {
      $a = $_ -split '\s*=\s*'
      if ( $a[1].SubString(0, 1) -eq '(' ) {
        New-Variable $a[0] ($a[1] -replace '[()]' -split ',')
      } else {
        New-Variable $a[0] $a[1]
      }
    }
    Write-Host "RegValues:" $RegValues
    Write-Host "RegServices:" $RegServices
    Write-Host "IsWin7OS:" $IsWin7OS
    Write-Host "IsSPInstalled:" $IsSPInstalled


But when I run this code 2nd time is gives error

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER: This is a security WORST practice. It really is quite dangerous.** That said, an easy way to read in this data is:

```
PS> Invoke-Expression (Get-Content C:\readfile.txt -Raw)
PS> $RegPath[0]
\\hklm\software\microsoft\123
```

The reason it is bad is that if someone adds this `remove-item c:\ -recurse -force` to the file the command above will execute that and it will be a bad day for you.  What I recommend is that you put the data in a `.psd1` file if you can in the form of a hashtable.  PowerShell will not execute arbitrary code in that case.  Or you could store the data as CLIXML or JSON and then read it back in with Import-Csv or ConvertFrom-Json.